# Add a user to SP group using REST API

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to add user to SP group with worklflow. Am using REST api to achieve it and by making a HTTP service call from the workflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a user to a SharePoint group, you need to pass the following REST call:

```
executor.executeAsync({
  url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web
    /sitegroups(7)/users
    ?@target='<host web url>'",
  method: "POST",
  body: "{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' }, 'LoginName':'i:0#.w|domain\\user' }",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
    "content-type": "application/json; odata=verbose"
  },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});
```

(Reference: [Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCollectionRequestExamples))

To handle the same in a Workflow, you need to define a request dictionary, define a metadata dictionary and finally calling parameters dictionary. Then you can make the call in the Wf. There's a lengthy post showing an example in here: http://codelesssharepointinfopath.com/workflow-useful-rest-calls-add-user-to-group/. Due to the length, I'll only pass it as a link