# Add User to SP2013 Group using API

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-rest-api

I need help figuring out my error. I am using Alteryx to POST to add a user to a permission group in SP2013. The components of how it's compiled are similar to this post: [Add a user to SP group using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219150/add-a-user-to-sp-group-using-rest-api)

URLToAddUser:   https://team.global.abcd/sites/SiteName/_api/web/sitegroups(4321)/users

Headers:

Accept:         application/json;odata=verbose

Content-Type:   application/json;odata=verbose

X-RequestDigest:    myauthenticationNumber

body/JSON:         "{'__metadata':{'type':'SP.User'},'LoginName':'i:0#.w|abcd\12345678'}"

DownloadData Error

{"error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON content."}}}

Answer (score 1):

The valid body for this request is just the login name:

```
{'LoginName':'abcd\\12345678'}
```

*unlike the list item actions you do not need to add the __metadata blurb...*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, that does not work for me:
{'LoginName':'abcd\\12345678'}
Same JSON error
:-(

Comment: Have you tried the same request using Postman? just to eliminate that Alteryx is doing something nasty?

Also try the same request with a GET to verify that everything else is correct... It should return the members of the group.

According to the error message "A token was not recognized", as if an invalid (or unescaped) character was in the body...

Comment: Long weekend.  Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try today.

Comment: Still not working. My code sends this {'LoginName':'abcd\\12345678'} format but no luck. I'll keep trying